# Bounds on minimum solutions to empirical and theoretical objective functions

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two probability distributions and let

$$S_0 = \min_{f,g} \left[ \int f(x)\, dP(x) + \int g(y)\, dQ(y) \right]$$ such that $f(x)+g(y) \geq \langle{x,y\rangle}$ where $f,g$ are strongly convex. This is a Wasserstein semi-dual except with the strongly convex restriction.

Now say I want to estimate the above but I only have points $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \hat{P}$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n \in \hat{Q}$ to work with.

Compute $$S^{*} =\min_{\hat{f_i},\hat{g_i},\nabla\hat{f_i},\nabla\hat{g_i}} \left[ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{f}_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{g}_i \right]$$ where

$\hat{f_i}+\hat{g_j} \geq \langle{x_i,y_j\rangle}$,

$\hat{f_i} \geq \hat{f_j} + \langle{\nabla\hat{f_j},x_i-x_j\rangle} + \frac{c}{2}\left\|x_j-x_i\right\|^2$,

and $\hat{g_i} \geq \hat{g_j} + \langle{\nabla\hat{g_j},y_i-y_j\rangle} + \frac{c}{2}\left\|y_j-y_i\right\|^2$

for all $i,j$. So we can think of $\hat{f_i},\hat{g_i},\nabla\hat{f_i},\nabla\hat{g_i}$ as being updated repeatedly after starting off with some suitable values at initialization.

Is there anything one can say about $S_0-S^*$? I thought of using some results on suboptimality gaps for strongly convex functions from Nesterov but now I'm minimizing over $f$ and $g$ instead of only $f$....